# Excel VBA Listbox to Filter excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, filter, listbox, userform

I have a listbox1 which populates a second listbox2 upon selecting an item from the first listbox. I am trying to come up with a code for listbox2 to filter the data in my excel spreadsheet based upon the selection. However, I am new to vba and  I am struggling because:

1. my code for listbox2 is not filtering data and
2. as of right now the code is static for one column.

In order for my code to work it needs to be dynamic in determining want column to filter. I added my code below:

- A) Initialize
- B) Listbox1 Click
- C)Listbox2 Click

**Section C** is where my code fails

---

**Section A**

**Userform initialize:**

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ListBox1
    .AddItem "State"
    .AddItem "County"
    .AddItem "City"
End With

ListBox1.Font.Size = 12
ListBox1.Font.Name = "Arial"

End Sub
```

**Section B**

**Listbox 1 Click**

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Dim x As Integer

x = ListBox1.ListIndex

Select Case x

    Case Is = 0

        'code to add a unique list to user form when selecting budim yer

        'With ListBox2
        '
        '    .AddItem "Michael"
        '    .AddItem "Kassie"
        'End With


        Dim myCollection As Collection, cell As Range

        On Error Resume Next

        Set myCollection = New Collection

        With ListBox2
            .Clear

            For Each cell In Range("O11:O6000")

                If Len(cell) <> 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    myCollection.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
                    If Err.Number = 0 Then .AddItem cell.Value
                End If

            Next cell

        End With

    Case Is = 1

        Dim my2Collection As Collection, cell_2 As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set my2Collection = New Collection

        With ListBox2
            .Clear

            For Each cell_2 In Range("D11:D6000")

                If Len(cell_2) <> 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    my2Collection.Add cell_2.Value, cell_2.Value
                    If Err.Number = 0 Then .AddItem cell_2.Value
                End If

            Next cell_2

        End With

    Case Is = 2

        Dim my3Collection As Collection, cell_3 As Range

        On Error Resume Next

        Set my3Collection = New Collection

        With ListBox2
            .Clear

            For Each cell_3 In Range("F11:F6000")

                If Len(cell_3) <> 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    my3Collection.Add cell_3.Value, cell_3.Value
                    If Err.Number = 0 Then .AddItem cell_3.Value
                End If

            Next cell_3

        End With
        End With              ' << Edit:  double End With ??? :-;

End Select

ListBox2.Font.Size = 12
ListBox2.Font.Name = "Arial"

End Sub
```

**Section C**

**Listbox 2 Click** ***This is where my code fails***

```
Private Sub ListBox2_Click()

Dim str As String
str = ListBox2.Text
Worksheets("Report").Range("A10:AE6000").AutoFilter Field:=2, criteria:="str"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `str` is already a variable of string type there is no need to place it in quotes in this statement:

`Worksheets("Report").Range("A10:AE6000").AutoFilter Field:=2, criteria:="str"`

Change it to the variable representation:

`Worksheets("Report").Range("A10:AE6000").AutoFilter Field:=2, criteria:=str`